# How can I make a gridView in yii-booster bootstrap widget with popups for buttons in one of its column

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am a fresher in Yii, I need to make a gridView for employee details in Yii, for that I have followed the procedures mentioned in http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/components.html#tables.
And I have created a gridView with some sample data, exactly like clevertech.biz has done, and i succeeded in that. But my actual requirement is to make a gridView with popup windows for viewing and editing employee details and a javascript confirmation before deleting entries. Here is my code, that created a grid and a popup window but the actions for each button is not separated, the popup works for the entire cell under a particular column, not for a button in that cell. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

```
$stu->id = 3;
$stu->name = 'Stu';
$stu->address = 'Dent';
$stu->position = 'SE';
$stu->joinDate = '2012-12-14';
$stu->age = 30;
$stu->phone = 1112226789;


$persons = array($mark, $jacob, $stu);
$gridDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($persons);

// $gridColumns
$gridColumns = array(
    array('name'=>'id', 'header'=>'#', 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 60px')),
    array('name'=>'name', 'header'=>'Name'),
    array('name'=>'address', 'header'=>'Address'),
    array('name'=>'position', 'header'=>'Position'),
    array('name'=>'joinDate', 'header'=>'Join Date'),
    array('name'=>'age', 'header'=>'Age'),
    array('name'=>'phone', 'header'=>'Phone'),

    array('header'=>'Options',
        'htmlOptions' => array('data-toggle'=>'modal',
        'data-target'=>'#myModal'),
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        'viewButtonUrl'=>null,
        'updateButtonUrl'=>null,
        'deleteButtonUrl'=>null,),


);


$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'type'=>'bordered',
    'dataProvider'=>$gridDataProvider,
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'columns'=>$gridColumns,
));
?>

 <!-- View Popup  -->
<?php    
$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id'=>'myModal')); ?>

<!-- Popup Header --> 
<div class="modal-header">
<h4>View Employee Details</h4>
</div>

<!-- Popup Content -->
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Employee Details</p>
</div>


<!-- Popup Footer -->
<div class="modal-footer">

<!-- save button -->
<?php  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
'type'=>'primary',
'label'=>'Save',
'url'=>'#',
'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
));  ?>
<!-- save button end-->

<!-- close button -->
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
'label'=>'Close',
'url'=>'#',
'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
)); ?>
<!-- close button ends-->
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
<!-- View Popup ends -->
```

Answer (score 4):

My columns its a little bit different but i think you'll understand.

You'll have to change your TbButtonColumn this way:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'type'=>'bordered',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'language',
        'hours',
        array(
            'header'=>'Options',
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'buttons'=>array(
                'view'=>
                    array(
                        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("person/view", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                        'options'=>array(
                            'ajax'=>array(
                                'type'=>'POST',
                                'url'=>"js:$(this).attr('href')",
                                'success'=>'function(data) { $("#viewModal .modal-body p").html(data); $("#viewModal").modal(); }'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
            ),
        )
    )));
?>

<!-- View Popup  -->
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id'=>'viewModal')); ?>
<!-- Popup Header -->
<div class="modal-header">
<h4>View Employee Details</h4>
</div>
<!-- Popup Content -->
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Employee Details</p>
</div>
<!-- Popup Footer -->
<div class="modal-footer">

<!-- close button -->
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Close',
    'url'=>'#',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
)); ?>
<!-- close button ends-->
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
<!-- View Popup ends -->
```

and your actionView from your personController this way:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    if( Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest )
        {
        $this->renderPartial('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ), false, true);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
}
```

and then, all you have to do it's do the same thing with your update.

If you can't understand anything, feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Thank you for the example of overriding a button's url.

Answer (score 0):

Refer: TbButtonColumn class file (TbButtonColumn.php)

@param array $button the button configuration which may contain 'label', 'url', 'imageUrl' and 'options' elements.

```
    array(
                'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
                'buttons'=>array(
                        'view'=>array(
                            'visible'=>'true/false',
                            'label'=>'Description',
                            'url'=>'link',
                            'imageUrl'=>'linkImage',
                            'options'=>array(
                            ),
                        ),
                ),
    ),
```